# Cannot validate argument on parameter 'Container'. The argument is null or empty

Tags: azure, powershell-5.1, azure-backup-vault, azure-site-recovery

I’m working on triggering an on-demand backup for my machines. But while running ps script it shows the below error.
"Cannot validate argument on parameter 'Container'. The argument is null or empty. Provide an argument that is not null or empty, and then try the command again".

```
$vault = Get-AzRecoveryServicesVault -ResourceGroupName "xxxx" -Name "xxxx"
Set-AzRecoveryServicesVaultContext -Vault $vault
$backupcontainer = Get-AzRecoveryServicesBackupContainer -ContainerType "AzureVM" -FriendlyName "testvm"
$item = Get-AzRecoveryServicesBackupItem -Container $backupcontainer -WorkloadType "AzureVM"
```

the above code was working fine couple of months ago. I have tried using different vm names in -FriendlyName but no luck.

Please suggest

Comment: The above script should add existing vm to the recovery vault? or it will only trigger backup for existing vms?

Answer (score 0):

The PowerShell response is that `Get-AzRecoveryServicesBackupContainer` do not respond a valid container object but `$null`.
Why I don't know.

But you should test the return values of the CmdLets you call before using them in other CmdLets.

Comment: I did try to run the CmdLets "Get-AzRecoveryServicesBackupContainer" and its not returning any value.

Comment: That's why `$backupcontainer` is `$null`, you've got your answer.

Comment: I am not sure why is it showing null, had provided -FriendlyName with existing vm name. Can you please suggest what mistake i am doing?

Comment: Sorry, I'am not in your organisation, you can try `-verbose` to understant.

Comment: Do we need to add vm to recovery vault prior to running script? or will script be adding the vm?